# How to handle java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded gracefully?

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, garbage-collection, glassfish

I wrote a pretty simple report for a client in Java/JSF which basically returns rows from a table in a mysql database based on some simple search criteria (start and end date, etc). This database contains a huge number of rows, but in the past there was a restriction that only rows of a certain type be returned and these rows only constitute about 1% of the table.

Recently, the client asked my to add a checkbox to the search criteria allowing them to bypass the restriction on which rows to return. If you check that box and leave a wide date range, it's possible to try and retrieve a massive ResultSet, after which the user is redirected to a Glassfish error page with the pleasant message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit.

Every response to posts I've found about regarding this error basically says "Don't catch Out Of Memory errors", and I get why: you can't really predict where an OOM error will show itself, even if you know where it's being caused.

I'd like to know how to handle this more gracefully than with a Glassfish error page though. Ideally, I'd like to be able to just take the user back to the search page with a message telling them to narrow their criteria if the criteria were too broad. Is there a nice way to do this before I run out of memory? Or is the best solution to put an arbitrary limit on the search results (maybe run the query with count() first, and if it returns more than X, return to search page with an error message?)

Comment: Yeah, this isn't done for a good reason. It indicates a real error, not just an exception. Your options are to paginate the data, stream results without holding it all in memory or increase your heap.

Comment: for results of unbounded size you should stream them instead. e.g. with a cursor-based approach and streaming the http output

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use pagination. How much records user really can see on the screen? Let's say 100. So, you display first 100 rows and navigator to the next page with the next 100 rows. But, of course, it depends on business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For results of unbounded size you should stream them instead of attempting to render the page in full before sending it.

E.g. with a cursor-based approach and streaming the http output. That way the server will only need to keep a limited amount of state and at worst the user's browser becomes unusable due to the large page.